# How to check whether the Grid contains Button or other element?

Tags: wpf, uwp

Clicking on the Canvas creates a Grid that contains the Textbox. Hover over the TextBox, a Button is added in this Grid. How to check the existence of the button in the Grid, not to create a duplicate. I tried

```
if(!((Grid)sender).Children.Contains(Button))
{
      DeleteButton deleteButton = new DeleteButton();
      ((Grid)sender).Children.Add(deleteButton);
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: your question has not enough information.Please add more information,what you have tried and ask specific question.

Comment: Please add your xaml to the question

Comment: @Kim Hoang, I create elements dynamically with C#

Comment: if(!((Grid)sender).Children.Contains(Button)), what is this Button in your if condition?

Comment: @KimHoang, I don't want add deletebutton, if I have already created deletebutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var yourButton = ((Grid)sender).Children.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return the first child of type Button if one exists.